# How to lose input focus when device orientates?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, mobile

I've noticed that iOS devices lock the view of your website when you're focused on a form element and change orientation.

I was wondering if there is a way to modify this code already implemented to include the functionality to lose `<input>` & `<select>` focus on orientation whether landscape or portrait?

Here is the code I have already:

```
// Fix HTML width issues on device orientation

window.document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
  var iOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g);
  var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
  if (iOS && viewportmeta) {
    if (viewportmeta.content.match(/width=device-width/)) {
      viewportmeta.content = viewportmeta.content.replace(/width=[^,]+/, 'width=1');
    }
    viewportmeta.content = viewportmeta.content.replace(/width=[^,]+/, 'width=' + window.innerWidth);
  }
  // If you want to hide the address bar on orientation change, uncomment the next line
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, false);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Eureka!**

```
window.document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(){
    if (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90){
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
    else if(window.orientation === 0) {
        var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
        viewportmeta.content = viewportmeta.content.replace(/width=[^,]+/, 'width=' + window.innerWidth);
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, false);
```